# Legend over my bar chart and can't seem to fix it

Tags: r, graph

The legend is showing over the chart and could not fix it even though I tried many codes

```
barplot(Type.freq, main="Breast Canser Classes", col=blues9, border = "black",legend=rownames(Type.freq), args.legend = list(title = "Type", x = "topright", cex = .4)) paste(prop.table(Type.freq)*100, "%", sep = "")
```

**Sample Data:**

```
(A1BG = c(5.620562952, 7.591106401, 8.348814005, 7.399435165, 7.494443613, 7.005119237, 7.825150239, 9.84125156, 7.711686244, 8.019511781)A2LD1 = c(5.243981286, 6.148334212,7.334008637, 6.853456781, 7.026735889, 5.723555831, 7.032773092, 5.538007298, 6.077351966, 6.283886593), Class = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: either move it or maybe make it smaller ...

Comment: @DarrenRhodes how to make it in the code itself

Comment: you haven't supplied a reproducible example, the code when copied and pasted into RStudio doesn't return your barplots.